# Display TFS Work Item edit form

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

The form layout for a workitem is stored in the DisplayForm field. How can I generate a form with that information?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking here.

Comment: You want to generate a work item form using the layout information stored in TFS?  Are you trying to write your own Team Explorer?  Or is there something else you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to generate a work itrm form using the layout information stored in TFS.

Comment: I think you may be on your own here. You may be able to call team explorer programatically to get it to show forms, but I wouldn't put much hope in that working.

Comment: I partially found my answer , that i have to use WorkItemFormControl control. I dont know how to use it. Can anyone help ??

Answer (score 2):

check this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163443.aspx#S5

and this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsworkitemtracking/thread/4576b799-c284-4848-b381-1361fee5685c/